# GridView-generated code adds "width='100%'" to the table it creates

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit

My page looks correct in Firefox and IE8.  But in IE7, a nested gridview spills into the adjacent cell, much like the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240802/textbox-within-table-grows-beyond-100-width-ie-only).

Looking at it in the developer tools, there is an inline-style associated with the table that ASP.NET generated, and it has a width attribute of 100%.  If I remove this, the nested table pops back where it belongs.

Problem is, nowhere is an inline-style set.  In fact, if I try to set `width='250px'`, it gets overridden with `width='100%'`.  If I try to remove the width attribute in the code-behind, `attrGridView.Attributes["Width"]` is null, and calling `.Remove()` does nothing.  But every asp.net-generated gridview-table has an inline style with `width='100%'` set on it (it's only causing me issues in one place).

Setting `table-layout='fixed'`, as suggested in the article I linked to, did not help.

How do I get ASP.NET to stop setting this property?

Some code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Attributes" SortExpression="Attributes">
  <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeaderCell" />
  <ItemStyle CssClass="GridTableCell AttrGridCellPadding" />
  <ItemTemplate>

    <asp:GridView id="attributesGridView" runat="server"
         AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false" GridLines="None" 
         AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" CssClass="StupidGridView" > 

      <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <p class="italic">There are no attributes for this request.</p>
      </EmptyDataTemplate>

      <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemStyle CssClass="AttrTableCell" />
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label id="attributeName" runat="server" 
                 Text='<%# Eval("Name") + ":&nbsp;&nbsp; "+ Eval("Value") %>'
                 CssClass="AttrGridCell"></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


.StupidGridView {
  width:  250px;
}
```

Comment: do you have a theme specified anywhere? if a theme is being applied to the gridview it's possible it would overwrite control-level settings.

Comment: lincolnk, you nailed it!  I'm not using gridview themes, but someone else in the project is.  I can override that on my gridviews, no problem.  If you post as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Themes are being applied and overriding control-level settings. Check theme settings on page, web.config, or anywhere else a theme may be set.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the ASP.NET html rendering is really bad.
Microsoft know that and provided [Control adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67276kc5.aspx) in 2006 which allow you to modify control rendering.

Instead of searching on how to override what ASP.NET render, I would advise to use [CSSFriendly](http://cssfriendly.codeplex.com/) which provides control adapters for most ASP.NET bad-rendered controls.

If you don't need "pure-css rendering" and CSS afraid you, you can check how they do to create your own adapter.

[ScottGu post on this subject](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/21/asp-net-2-0-control-adapter-architecture.aspx) from google.

Comment: Upvoted for the Control Adapter suggestion and link to Scott Gu's article.  I will definitely look more into this!